# How to find the oldest Folder in a Folder vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a program that backs up folders. I want to have say 5 folders, then if it is backed up again I want the oldest of the 5 folders to be deleted and the new one placed in it.

How would I find the oldest folder in a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) could be helpful.

Specifically with regards to the `CreationTime` property and `EnumerateDirectories` method.

Here is a modified sample for the EnumerateDirectories method using LINQ:

```
' Create a DirectoryInfo of the Program Files directory.
Dim dirPrograms As New DirectoryInfo("c:\program files")

' LINQ query for oldest directory
Dim dir = (From dir In dirPrograms.EnumerateDirectories()).Min(function (o) o.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault()

If Not IsNothing(dir) Then
' perform rest of function
End If
```

Here is a non LINQ version to get the oldest directory in a folder:

```
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\program files")
    Dim dirs() as DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
    Dim creationTime as DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim oldestDir As DirectoryInfo

    For Each dir As DirectoryInfo In dirs
        If DateTime.Compare(dir.CreationTime(), creationTime) < 0 Then
            oldestDir = dir
            creationTime = dir.CreationTime()
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: @ash Basically, my folders will be created within hours of each other. Is there a way i can just say, `directory.lastmodifieddate.oldest delete`

Comment: @Kuzon I added a non-LINQ version. As far as I know, this is the best way to get the oldest directory in a directory.

Comment: @Ash thankyou, I am still quite new to Vb, how do i fix the error that i get on this line `creationTime = f.CreationTime()` Error 1 'f' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level... do i declare it as a string?

Comment: My mistake - dodgy typo. I have updated the answer with ```dir.CreationTime()```

Comment: @Ash :) so now all i need to do is `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory("C:\program files\" + oldestdir, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)`... right?

Comment: I think oldestDir will have a ```Name``` property if you want to do ```("C:\program files\" & oldestdir, ...```, but I would also check out the ```oldestDir.FullName``` property also. MSDN states that Full Name gives a full filepath.