# VB.NET error using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using the following example from Stackoverflow: 
[How to find the oldest Folder in a Folder vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528524/how-to-find-the-oldest-folder-in-a-folder-vb-net)

```
Dim dirPrograms As New DirectoryInfo("c:\program files")

' LINQ query for oldest directory
Dim dir = (From dir In dirPrograms.EnumerateDirectories()).Min(function (o) o.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault()
```

I get the following error:
Range variable 'dir' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression.

No one else is complaining about an error so I assume I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:-

```
Dim directoryInfo = (From dir In dirPrograms.EnumerateDirectories())
                        .Min(function (o) o.CreationTime)
```

Your `dir` declared variable (where you are storing the result) is same as your range variable `dir` in query-`From dir In dirPrograms..` so compiler is complaining as these names will be obviously confusing between the two, So you need to change either of the two names.

Apart from this, You should not use `FirstOrDefault` after a `Min` as Min method will return a single value and not `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I had already tried that thinking it might help, but it gives me this error instead: 'FirstOrDefault' is not a member of 'Date'

Comment: @rerat - That's obviously a different error. Min will return just a single value and not `IEnumerable` so no need of 'FirstOrDefault'. Please check my edit.